# How to build a queryset in a specific order in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-queryset

I'm trying to list profiles of users. I want to list them in such a way that profiles with same city of the user should come first, then next priority should be state, then country, and finally, rest of the profiles. This is what I have tried. 
model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    uuid = UUIDField(auto=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, null=True)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True)
```

views.py
    current_user = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)

```
profiles_city = Profile.objects.filter(city=current_user.city)
profiles_state = Profile.objects.filter(state=current_user.state)
profiles_country = Profile.objects.filter(country=current_user.country)
profiles_all = Profile.objects.all()
profiles = (profiles_city | profiles_state | profiles_country | profiles_all).distinct()
```

But it is yielding the same result as Profile.objects.all()

Please help me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) method of `QuerySet` that orders objects based on passed parameters; this is done on database:

```
Profile.objects.order_by(
    'current_user__city',
    'current_user__state',
    'current_user__country',
)
```

---

**Edit:**

If you want to sort by the `city`, `state` and `country` names of the logged in user, you can do this on the Python level, using `sorted`, and a custom `key` callable:

```
from functools import partial


def get_sort_order(profile, logged_in_profile):
    # This is a simple example, you need to filter against
    # the city-state-country combo to match precisely. For
    # example, multiple countries can have the same city/
    # state name.

    if logged_in_profile.city == profile.city: 
        return 1 
    if logged_in_profile.state == profile.state: 
        return 2 
    if logged_in_profile.country == profile.country: 
        return 3
    return 4 

logged_in_profile = request.user.profile  # logged-in user's profile
get_sort_order_partial = partial(get_sort_order, logged_in_profile=logged_in_profile)

sorted(
    Profile.objects.all(),
    key=get_sort_order_partial,
)
```

---

Doing the same on the database level, using `Case` and `When` to have a Python `if`-`elif`-`else` like construct:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, IntegerField

Profile.objects.order_by( 
    Case( 
        When(city=logged_in_profile.city, then=1), 
        When(state=logged_in_profile.state, then=2), 
        When(country=logged_in_profile.country, then=3), 
        default=4, 
        output_field=IntegerField(), 
    ) 
)
```

This will result in a queryset and also has the added advantage of being faster as all the operations would be done on the database (`SELECT CASE WHEN ...`).

Comment: It's giving field error
Cannot resolve keyword 'current_user' into field.
this is the current_user 
current_user = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)

Comment: @ArunLaxman Replace `current_user` with the actual field name you have; if it's `user` then use `Profile.objects.order_by('user__city')` and so on.

Comment: Still error. I've updated the question with more details. I'm trying to sort the queryset in the order of city,state,country of the profile of the logged in user

Comment: Umm.. this gives back a list. Is there anyway to retrieve it as queryset?

Comment: @ArunLaxman Where are you passing this data to? Unless you're doing further queryset-like operations on this, it is perfectly fine.

Comment: There are further queryset operations going on. It's an old project in django 1.7 and I was asked to implement this list by region feature.

Comment: Thanks for being so persistant. unfortunately Case is introduced in django 1.8 and the project is in django 1.7. gotta try upgrading to 1.8.

Comment: @ArunLaxman 1.7 is long gone, you should upgrade anyway. While upgrading, try to upgrade to a supported release e.g. 1.11/2.2 (as of the time of this writing), not to 1.8 (as it is also not supported now).